# How to put this standard sql to laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How to put this standard sql to laravel 5.3 query?

```
SELECT a.emp_id, d.course_code, d.start_time, d.end_time,
( SELECT time FROM hris_biometrics_attendance WHERE date = '2017-06-13' AND time BETWEEN d.start_time - 1 AND d.end_time -1 AND emp_id = a.emp_id) AS time_in,
( SELECT time FROM hris_biometrics_attendance WHERE date = '2017-06-13' AND time BETWEEN d.end_time - 1 AND d.end_time + 1 AND emp_id = a.emp_id) AS time_out FROM hris_ftl_final_courses a, hris_ftl_final_courses_details d
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = your query ;
return DB::select($sql);